# Invalid remote IP address in TCP server in docker container

Tags: docker, ip-address, tcplistener, tcpserver

I have a tcp server nodejs that some clients can connect to it and authenticate base on ip address but tcp server in docker can not find valid remote ip address for clients.each client when connect to server invalid 172.17.0.1 address found for remote address.is there any way to find real remote ip address?

Answer (score 1):

The containers in Docker work in their own namespace that is isolated from the host, so they get separate IP address. The port exposed on the host will be forwarded to the container, so during this process you will loose the origin IP.

If you are on a linux host, you can create a `host` network for the container as described in the [documents](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) to create a container that is in the same namespace with the host netowork.

When you start the container with `--network host` you will be in the same network namespace as the host, so there will be no additional routing involved.

Example:

```
docker run --rm -d --network host <container>
```

If you are running docker inside a virtual machine (such as Docker for Mac, or Docker for Windows), then you will need to create a bridge between the container network and the host network. Here are some sites that can help

- [Windows bridge](https://forums.docker.com/t/bridge-with-docker-for-windows/30936/5)
- [Mac bridge using soctun](https://github.com/SciSpike/soctun)
- [Use CNF router in container](https://ttl255.com/vrnetlab-run-virtual-routers-in-docker-containers/)

Comment: when run by --networking host can not connect to TCP server, in addition in docker document said:
The host networking driver only works on Linux hosts and is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac, Docker Desktop for Windows, or Docker EE for Windows Server.

Comment: Then add details in your question: where are the clients, where are you running the server, etc. If you intend to run the docker-engine inside a Vitrual Machine (like on Mac or Windows) than you will need to setup networking bridge between the container network and the host network.

Comment: I have a docker desktop on windows 10 and clients exists on the network that connected to each other by switch

Comment: As I said, you need to establish a bridge network and work with the routing. Try the following [article](https://forums.docker.com/t/bridge-with-docker-for-windows/30936/5). Also, consider moving to linux host

Comment: It's worth mentioning that docker-mac-net-connect does the same thing as soctun, but even better and easier. https://github.com/chipmk/docker-mac-net-connect